# How can I find a maximal inscribed ellipsoid to a *concave* set of points, in 3D?

Tags: calculus, optimization, algorithms, computational-geometry

I have a set of points which describe the surface of an irregular, natural (i.e., occurs in nature) object. This point set is not necessarily convex, and contains occasional indentations so parts of it are concave. There are well-described methods for determining maximal ellipsoids in convex polytopes, and minimal enclosing ellipsoids for any set of points, but so far I haven't found a method to determine a maximal volume ellipsoid which fits inside a shape with some convex and some concave portions.

Comment: Do you want it to fit inbetween the points or in the polyhedron whose vertices are the points?

Comment: Assume your point set consists of $7$ points: the vertices of a regular hexagon in the plane, and the center of this hexagon. There are many maximal inscribed ellipsoids in this case.

Comment: @Juris, the points, when I think about it.

Comment: @Christian, that's true, although I think my point set will be quite different to your hexagon example as the cloud rests on a closed, curved surface. Good consideration though. If there are multiple overlapping 'locally maximal' ellipsoids' then that's interesting too.

Comment: I don't know of one such method.

I'd say you have to divide the object into all possible convex parts and find maximal ellipsoids in each of the parts separately.